# Upgrading my Macbook Pro from 2GB to 4GB. Worth It?

Tags: memory, macbook

I looked online and I can upgrade my 2 year old Macbook Pro, 17 inch, from 2GB to 4GB for around £64. (Roughly $100).

I was wondering your opinions on if it was worth the upgrade? I mostly use my Mac for video watching, Internet surfing, and so on. I often have a few small applications running.

Your views?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no hard numbers but I saw a drastic improvement on my MBP when I went from 2 to 4 GB.

Especially with multiple apps open, it made a difference for me.

Normally I'm running the following:

```
Textmate
Firefox - 6-8 open tabs
Navicat
Pixelmator
NetNewWire
```

I also run the laptop as a Apache server (PHP & mySQL) where I'm doing development.

If you use any virtual applications (VMWare, Parallels, etc...) you'll get great results.

Answer (score 2):

**Measure your memory usage, then deiced.**

Use Activity Monitor to see how much free memory you have in everyday usage.  If you have >25% free, then I would not worry about it.  If you have <10% then I'd think about upgrading.  In between?  Eh...either way...

How much longer do you think you'll have it?

Answer (score 2):

4Gb is the sweet spot for RAM on a recent Intel Mac. So if you plan to work with the Book for at least a year, do it. It will increase the second hand price too.

Answer (score 2):

I would say yes, I always put the maximum amount of ram possible in any notebook, just don't buy it direct from apple as you have to pay the apple tax.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the other posters.  4GB is the sweet spot for Macs - very noticeable performance gains.  I upgraded my MBP and can't imagine going back.

That said, if you are just surfing it may not be worth it for you.